# Problems loading remote Interface with context.lookup

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, jboss7.x

I used to work with jboss 4.2.3 GA and there everything worked fine (at least calling the remote interface from the client side). Now I try to deploy that with Jboss 7.0.1 FINAL

I have (on the server project) this class:

```
@Remote(ConfigurationHelperRemote.class)
@Local(ConfigurationHelperLocal.class)
@Stateless
public class ConfigurationHelper implements ConfigurationHelperRemote,  ConfigurationHelperLocal {
   ...
}
```

and I have the remote Interface

```
@Remote
public interface ConfigurationHelperRemote {
  ...
}
```

Now I used to call the remote interface from the client side with the help of context like this:

```
configurationHelper = (ConfigurationHelperRemote) ctx.lookup("ear-1.0.0/ConfigurationHelper/remote");
```

But this isn't working anymore. Now I get this error message

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name 'ear-1.0.0' not found in context ''
```

My ear file is called **ear-1.0.0.ear** and the  client inside is called **client-1.0.0.war** and the server is called **server-1.0.0.jar**.

This is the content of the application.xml inside the ear file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
   <display-name>ear</display-name>
     <module>
      <web>
       <web-uri>client-1.0.0.war</web-uri>
       <context-root>/client</context-root>
     </web>
    </module>
   <module>
    <ejb>server-1.0.0.jar</ejb>
   </module>
</application>
```

Where do I need to configure the context name? Or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot and many greetings,
Hauke

PS.: I just printed out all JNDI Context Information, and there is only the datasource from the database. I did this:

```
      public static void showJndiContext( Context ctx, String name, String space )
   {
      if( null == name  ) name  = "";
      if( null == space ) space = "";
      try {
         NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> en = ctx.list( name );
         while( en != null && en.hasMoreElements() ) {
            String delim = ( name.length() > 0 ) ? "/" : "";
            NameClassPair ncp = en.next();
            System.out.println( space + name + delim + ncp );
            if( space.length() < 40 )
               showJndiContext( ctx, ncp.getName(), "    " + space );
         }
      } catch( javax.naming.NamingException ex ) {

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Portable JNDI Syntax, the lookup name like this :

1. java:global[/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]
2. java:module/enterprise bean name/[interface name]
3. java:app[/module name]/enterprise bean name[/interface name]

your can see more detail at http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girgn

So for yoour code try

```
configurationHelper = (ConfigurationHelperRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/ear-1.0.0/server-1.0.0/ConfigurationHelper");
```

this format I used in my code for a remote bean...