# JNDI resource not found in Spring controller, but works in JSP

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

I have one Tomcat 5.5 with one resource for JDBC Pool connection:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/orcl"
           auth="Container"
           type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
           driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myip:myport:mydatabase"
       user="..."
       password="...
           implicitCachingEnabled="true"
           connectionCachingEnabled="true"
           connectionCacheProperties="{InitialLimit=10, MinLimit=10, MaxLimit=50, MaxStatementsLimit=0, ConnectionWaitTimeout=20}"
           connectionCacheName="cacheOrcl"
        />
```

And I have the following code to obtain the Connection:

```
Object o = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/orcl");
if( o instanceof DataSource ) {
  DataSource ds = (DataSource) o;
  con = ds.getConnection();
  LOGGER.debug(ds);
}
```

The interesting is that is working on a JSP, but not in one Spring Controller. In the spring controller I receive the message:

```
Name jdbc is not bound in this Context  
org.apache.naming.NamingContext NamingContext.java      770 lookup
org.apache.naming.NamingContext NamingContext.java      153 lookup
org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceLinkFactory
```

Comment: `<jee:jndi-lookup>` does not work as well? Try to declare it in your context and wire to your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Using jndi-lookup works local too. I will send one version of the app with this config for the client, to see if it works and post back the result here.

Comment: I will also try defining a bean inside applicationContext.xml: http://pro-programmers.blogspot.com/2008/07/spring-datasource-jndi-lookup-from.html

Comment: Have a look at the code snippet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293710) that prints the JNDI contents, or have a look around how to dump the JNDI tree. That will give you a hint, what's going wrong.

Comment: Well, I send my WAR again to the client, with some additional debug code and finally it works. I think I send before one WAR with the cast to OracleDataSource instead of DataSource inside my Spring Controller.
If the app still unstable, I will try those two methods commented before.

Thanks all for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the issue occurs, but I can suggest a better way to use jdbc with spring - using JdbcTemplate and the spring jdbc support - [see here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-connections) for a manual